# PowerBI DAX - Display column based on filter selection

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have one filter and one table as below;

[image]

I would like to have solution which **if any of filter selected**, table will display data with code 1

[image]

If **no filter selected**, table will display data with code 0

[image]

Comment: Student filter and student details - same table? or different? if different, are they related? Regarding showing 0 or 1, you can create a new slicer using column "code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this approach use separate table for filter values;
[image]
We can use a specific FilterMeasure to achieve your desired results.

```
IsFiltered = ISFILTERED(StudentName[Student])

Hide = 
SWITCH(TRUE(),
[IsFiltered] == FALSE && SELECTEDVALUE(students[Code])==0,1,
[IsFiltered] == TRUE && SELECTEDVALUE(students[Code])==1,1,
0)
```

[image]

[image]